# AngularJS not parsing some data from ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular2-template

The HTML code is:

```
<mydirective ui-if="isReady"></mydirective>
```

and the directive codes is:

```
app.directive('mydirective', ['$http', '$window' ,'opt', function ($http, $window, opt) {

  return {
            strict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: opt.base_url + 'mytemplate',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                $http({
                    url: opt.api_url + 'projects',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'GET',
                }).then(function (response) {
                    scope.projects = response.data;
                    scope.isReady = true;
                });
            },
  };
}]);
```

mytemplate returns this html code:

```
<project ng-repeat="project in projects" projects="{{$scope.projects}}">
  <img ng-src="{{$project.owner.avatar_url}}">
  <h2>@{{project.name}}</h2>
</project>
```

Angular parses the h2 tag titles correctly. The problem is that the ng-src value does not aprse at all and contains the literal `{{$project.owner.avatar_url}}` string.

Result:

```
<project ng-repeat="project in projects">
       <img ng-attr-src="{{$project.owner.avatar_url}}">
       <h2>Project #1</h2>
</project>

<project ng-repeat="project in projects">
       <img ng-attr-src="{{$project.owner.avatar_url}}">
       <h2>Project #2</h2>
</project>
```

Any idea what's causing this strange behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using `$project`. just use the `project.owner.avatar_url`

```
 <img ng-src="{{project.owner.avatar_url}}">`
```

also don't use the `$scope` in the html

```
<project ng-repeat="project in projects" projects="{{projects}}">
```

Comment: ugh haha! a typo. thanks for pointing it out. 
btw, i'm using $scope.projects so as not to over clutter the DOM. using ``projects`` alone appends the actual json to the ``projects`` tag.

Comment: post ur full json